# Real time speech transformation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, real-time, signal-processing, speech, pitch

Is it possible to transform speech (pitch/formant shift) in (near) real-time using MATLAB? How can it be done?

If not, what should I use to do that?

I need to get input from the microphone, visualise the sound wave, add a filter to it, see the oscilloscope again, and play back the modified sound.

The real-time visualization (spectrogram) can be created with [SparkNG](http://www.wakayama-u.ac.jp/~kawahara/MatlabRealtimeSpeechTools/) package by Hideki Kawahara.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. There's a [demo application](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2904-3d-waterfall-plot-demo/content/daqwaterfall.m) up on the MATLAB Central File Exchange that does something similar. It reads in a signal from the sound card (requires Data Acquisition Toolbox) in near real time, applies an FFT transform - you could do something else like applying a filter - and visualises the results in 3D graphs live. You could use it as a template and modify it to your needs, such as visualising in different ways (more of an oscilloscope style), or outputting the sound as a .wav file for later playback.

If you need properly real time, you might look into implementing in Simulink rather than just base MATLAB.

Comment: Unfortunately this is outdated for win64 systems